# Swift FSCalendar add event based on array of date

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to customise `FSCalendar`. Here, add multiple event in `calendar` options available but it is showing three `dots`. I need to do If two same date in the array need to show two dot also if three need to show three dot but above three also need to show only three dot. How to achieve this?

https://iosexample.com/a-fully-customizable-ios-calendar-library-compatible-with-objective-c-and-swift/

**My Code**

```
var datesWithEvent = ["02-09-2019", "03-09-2019", "07-09-2019", "09-09-2019"]
var datesWithMultipleEvents = ["03-09-2019", "03-09-2019", "02-09-2019", "09-09-2019"]

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {        
    let dateString = self.dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
        return 1
    }
    if self.datesWithMultipleEvents.contains(dateString) {
        return 3
    }
    return 0
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, eventDefaultColorsFor date: Date) -> [UIColor]? {
    let key = self.dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    if self.datesWithMultipleEvents.contains(key) {
        return [UIColor.magenta, appearance.eventDefaultColor, UIColor.black]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,Below answer for adjusting the `FSCalendar` dot UI count based on `JSON` array Data.

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) {
            return 1 // Here, We have to assign JSON count key value based on duplication it will increase dot count UI.
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: @Joakim Danielson this is my answer.

Comment: Yeah @Joakim Danielson

Comment: Maybe you should update your other question with this answer then to not confuse people or even remove the code from that question if it is no longer an issue.