# How to load JSON data date key values into FSCalendar event array using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case I have `JSON` data like below, Now I need to load JSON `date` key value into `FSCalendar` events array. So, based on JSON date event will be add into calendar. I am done almost JSON `codable` structure, `Decoding` but I don't know how to load date `key` `values` into array and assign to calendar event. Please help me on this.

**My JSON**

```
{  
   "status":true,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "count":1,
         "date":"23-09-2019"
      },
      {  
         "count":2,
         "date":"22-09-2019"
      }
   ]
}
```

**My Codable Structure**

```
struct Calendars: Codable {
        let status: Bool
        let data: [Cdata]
    }

    struct Cdata: Codable {
        let count: Int
        let date: String
    }
```

**My Code for FSCalendar**

How to assign my JSON Date and Count key values into below method.

```
    // MARK Calendar Data Fetch

   func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        if self.calendarsData.date.contains(dateString) { // Here how to assign JSON date values?
            return 1 // Here, How to assign JSON count key value?
        }
        return 0
    }
```

**JSON Data Load**

```
//var datesWithEvent = ["02-09-2019", "03-09-2019", "07-09-2019", "09-09-2019"] Instead this I need to use `calendarsData` array
 var calendarsData = [Cdata]() // Global Declaration Array For Date and Count Key Value 

// MARK: JSON Data Load - Calendar Data

    func loadCalendarsJSON(){
        let urlPath = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/9gq0h"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { data, response, error in
            guard data != nil && error == nil else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Calendars.self,  from: data!)
                let status = decoder.status
                if status == true {
                    self.calendarsData = decoder.data
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //self.calendar.reloadData()
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch { print(error) }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: It’s unclear what you are asking, is it about the error you got or...?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I updated my question. Please check it!

Comment: I am not sure what that means, are you referring to the method `calendar(numberOfEventsFor:)`? Also is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150174/swift-fscalendar-add-event-based-on-array-of-date?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson No its not duplicate. Here the question is how to load JSON date and count key value into FSCalendar. There, I asked for FSCalendar event dot UI count increasing and decreasing.

Comment: Ok, I answered your other question but this one I don't  understand.

Comment: @vaidan do you know answer for this question?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson do you know answer for this question?

Comment: @vadian help me on this question Please!

Answer (score 0):

As I am looking your code that you post you'r returning 3 in case of multiple event in a date but may be some times your dateArray having less then 3 events. Just return 3 or dateArray length in case of less than 3.
Please look the only change in case of datesWithMultipleEvents.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        if self.datesWithEvent.contains(dateString) { // Here need to fetch date array
            return 1
        }
        if self.datesWithMultipleEvents.contains(dateString) {
            return min(3, datesWithMultipleEvents.count) 
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Hope! it will help.

Comment: Thanks @Nakul Sharma I need to know how to load my JSON data into FSCalendar and if I receive same date in multiple time then need to add `datesWithMultipleEvents` then single need to add `self.datesWithEvent`. How to achieve this bro?

Comment: how to load my Date values into event array? Can you please help me on this?